# how to achieve high perfomance with istio

Tags: istio

I had installed istio on kubernets(hosted on aws ) and exposed a service as a via  istio ingress. I could achieve very less through put < 2000  requests per minute.  I exposed the service as a standard ELB, I was able to achieve >600,000 request per sec.  Is there any guide/steps to tune istio for high performance ? 
Thanks 
Joji

Comment: This is a question that's probably better suited to istio-users@googlegroups.com than Stack Overflow as it's hard to prescribe specific, generally useful advice here. The short answer is that in Istio 0.1, Mixer is called for every single request, greatly reducing throughput. Istio 0.2 has substantially higher throughput due to caching Mixer results, and performance is one of the critical features we'll be shipping for our 0.3 release. A more fair comparison to ELB would be using stock Envoy, or Istio's sidecar with Mixer disabled.

Answer (score 1):

One thing we recommend users to do is to switch to the non-debug image for the envoy side car, e.g. replace docker.io/istio/proxy_debug with docker.io/istio/proxy in the istio and istio-initializer yaml file and redeploy istio.  We are also working on reduce mixer traces.  Performance is an area we are very actively working on in the next release of Istio and we welcome contribution to this!